# How to get TLS certs into pod for use with Prometheus helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

Here is the helm chart values for `stable/prometheus`: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/values.yaml

I was able to get this to work:

```
helm upgrade --install prometheus stable/prometheus \
--set extraScrapeConfigs="- job_name: 'myjob'
  scrape_interval: 1s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['###.##.###.###:#####']
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /prometheus/ca.pem
    key_file: /prometheus/key.pem
    cert_file: /prometheus/cert.pem
    insecure_skip_verify: true"
```

In order to do this I had to do:

```
kubectl cp localdir/ca.pem prometheus-server-abc:/prometheus -c prometheus-server
kubectl cp localdir/key.pem prometheus-server-abc:/prometheus -c prometheus-server
kubectl cp localdir/cert.pem prometheus-server-abc:/prometheus -c prometheus-server
```

I believe there's a better and more proper way to do this with `Secret` and `mountPath`. I tried something like the following with no luck:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
data:
  ca.pem: base64encodedcapem
  key.pem: base64encodedkeypem
  cert.pem: base64encodedcertpem
```

```
kubectl apply -f mysecret
```

```
helm upgrade --install prometheus stable/prometheus \
--set extraSecretMounts="- name: mysecret-mount
  mountPath: /somepathinpod/mysecret
  secretName: mysecret" \
--set extraScrapeConfigs="- job_name: 'myjob'
  scrape_interval: 1s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['###.##.###.###:#####']
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /somepathinpod/mysecret/ca.pem
    key_file: /somepathinpod/mysecret/key.pem
    cert_file: /somepathinpod/mysecret/cert.pem
    insecure_skip_verify: true"
```

I expected the certs to magically show up at `/somepathinpod` but they did not.

I'm assuming I don't have to clone the whole repo and manually edit the helm chart to put a `volumeMount` into the `prometheus-server` deployment/pod and can just change my helm command somehow. Any advice on how to get my certs in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus), the correct key to use would be `server.extraSecretMounts` instead of just `extraSecretMounts`.

Also verify the generated YAML on Kubernetes to contain the correct mounts via:

```
kubectl get deployment prometheus-server-object-name -o yaml
```

**override.yaml**

```
server:
  extraSecretMounts:
    - name: mysecret-mount
      mountPath: /etc/config/mysecret
      secretName: mysecret

extraScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: myjob
    scrape_interval: 15s
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - ###.##.###.###:#####
    tls_config:
      ca_file: /etc/config/mysecret/ca.pem
      key_file: /etc/config/mysecret/key.pem
      cert_file: /etc/config/mysecret/cert.pem
      insecure_skip_verify: true
```

```
helm upgrade -f override.yaml prometheus stable/prometheus
```

Comment: Ah, good catch on the `server.extraSecretMounts`. I tried `--set "server\.extraSecretMounts"` but still don't see the mountPath available in the `-o yaml`.

Comment: Oh I was able to get it to work with `helm upgrade -f override.yaml prometheus stable/prometheus` where `override.yaml` contains only the yaml of the `server.extraSecretMounts`. Also seems a lot cleaner for object lists than using `--set`. Not sure why one works over the other is but `override.yaml` seems easier to manage and get working. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for finding that configuration. Will this work if my secret is in another namespace?